# IntelliJ pulling in maven-enforcer-plugin without it being explicitly part of the pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-enforcer-plugin

When doing a build from `IntelliJ` I get the error saying

```
org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
Detected Maven Version: 3.3.9 is not in the allowed range 3.6.0.
```

My maven Version is `3.3.9` and this is the one I want to stick to. I do recall when opening `IntelliJ` for the first time, going through a UI which asked me to specify a minimum and a maximum version for `Maven` and I did indeed specify `3.6` as a minimum. However I struggle to find the same settings at this point. Can someone point me to where `IntelliJ`'s settings for `Maven` version boundaries are?

I'm using `IntelliJ 2017.3.5`

Comment: I doubt that it will work cause the enforcer rule shows that the project you are working on requires 3.6.0 and up which usually has a reason and trying to go beyond that limit makes no sense...I strongly recommend to upgrade most recent version of Maven...(there is no real reason not to upgrade?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this path

`-> Menu > Preferences > Type: Maven or Go to Building, Execution: Maven > select your version - 3.3.9 from Maven home directory: dropwdown`

Make sure you downloaded and set maven environment as global variables on your PC